# Online wallet for betting / customer profile?

Tags: wallet, address, gambling

I am looking for a system that provides users with the option to deposit and withdraw BTC to a generated address.

Basically something that works like https://primedice.com/play and https://dicecoin.io/

On top of this, perhaps there is an all-in-one bitcoin dice system?

Thanks!

Comment: `I am looking for a system that provides users with the option to deposit and withdraw BTC to a generated address.` - That's pretty much what any wallet software does. `On top of this, perhaps there is an all-in-one bitcoin dice system?` - What exactly do you mean by 'all-in-one'?

Comment: @StephenM347 It sounds to me - and ManeBit, correct me if I'm wrong - that he's after code which he can use "off the shelf" to start his own dice site. If so, I'm 100% certain that's not going to be an option